# Template with TYPO3 v10

Tags: templates, typo3, typo3-10.x

I would like to do a project with TYPO3 v10 I'm new with this CMS and I need to create different templates for different pages but I don't understand which code I need to change.
I already install a sitepackage from this site https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/
It work well but I need to create my own templates and I want to edit the content of my templates in the back end administration like in the picture.

I hope I'm clear
thanks for help :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a misconception in the question or if I have interpreted incorrectly. In any case, I hope this helps:

It is important to differentiate between content + template in TYPO3:

### content

In the screenshot [posted in the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJujB.png), you see the *TYPO3 backend*, which is a view for editing content, administration etc. There you see the page module is opened in the left column (1), you see the page tree in the middle column (2) and the page layout for editing content on the selected page in the right column (3). Here, you can insert and edit the *content*, that will be displayed on a page.

### Template

In TYPO3, the template is what makes up the automatically generated parts of the page such as header, footer, menu, breadcrumb etc.

> It work well but I need to create my own templates and I want to edit the content of my templates in the back end administration like in the picture.

Editing the template in the backend with a Wysiwyg ("what you see is what you get") editor, similarly to editing the content is not really possible in TYPO3 AFAIK - at least not out of the box. For this, you would need a template builder. The only thing I have seen so far that comes close to this is [toujou](https://www.toujou.de/en/) (I am not affiliated with them, just wanted to mention it). They have something which you could call a website builder. But AFAIK, you can't download it, they provide this as a service.

The sitepackage builder - as far as I know - pretty much just creates a sitepackage based on the [bootstrap package extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/?L=0&id=1&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=bootstrap_package) which you would have to further modify by editing the files.

What you can also do is edit the TypoScript in the backend. Just go to the "Template" module in the left column. But, this made more sense in the past, because a lot more was done with TypoScript. Nowadays, you usually use a combination of [Fluid](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Fluid/Introduction.html) and TypoScript and you can't edit the Fluid files in the backend.

While in the past, a lot more was done in the backend or could be done in the backend, everything is moving towards maintaining changes in files and extensions, where the template is maintained in a sitepackage. For some things both is still possible (backend and extension), e.g. backend layouts, TypoScript etc.

Moving the configuration + templates from the backend (and storing them in the database or as files) to a dedicated extension has several advantages:

- Every configuration etc. is bundled into one extension, this makes it easier to install in another site, on a testsystem, exchange it etc.
- the sitepackage can be put in a version control system (e.g. git) which has a bunch of other advantages such as easy rollback to a previous version, referencing issues etc.

The downside is that you need more technical expertise and there is a learning curve.

see also:

- [The Anatomy of Sitepackages](https://www.slideshare.net/benjaminkott/typo3-the-anatomy-of-sitepackages)
- [Sitepackage Tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/)

---

I understand that it might be pretty cool to assemble a template in the backend - just like you can do with the content. Maybe someone else knows how to do that with TYPO3.

You can also check out these resources which seem to go in the direction of what you are looking for:

- TYPO3 extension [mask](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask/) ([documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/mask/stable/))
- [T3terminal](https://t3terminal.com/blog/typo3-templates-builder/)

Comment: I added links to mask and t3terminal

Answer (score 0):

in the [official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/10.4/en-us/FluidTemplates/Index.html#directory-structure) you can find the structure of folders where the files for your layout are stored.
More details on fluid templating in this [document](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-templating/10.4/en-us/)

Now you want a possibility for editors to select between different page layouts. An often used way is to use the possibility to select different backend layouts and select a frontend layout accordingly.
This is shown in the video on this [page](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-tell-me-something-about/master/en-us/Topics/BackendLayouts.html) or in the documents you can find if you uses the searches on that [page](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-tell-me-something-about/master/en-us/Topics/BackendLayouts.html).